# how to control trackwheel sensitivity in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

```
trackwheelRoll( int amount, int status, int time)
```

Is there a way to control the trackwheel sensitivity from this method?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you trying to change the trackwheel sensitivity system-wide?  Or are you just trying to change the way that it works in your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to lower it, you can set a `lastMoveTime` flag in your class. After that, in your `trackwheelRoll()` method you can compare the `time` to that and see if you should move. For example:

```
protected boolean trackwheelRoll(int amount, int status, int time) {
    if(time - lastMoveTime > someTimeThatYouDetermine) {
        lastMoveTime = time;
        return super.trackwheelRoll(amount, status, time);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'll set `someTimeThatYouDetermine` to control how much lower the sensitivity is. What this does is essentially discard some of the motion so it feels slower to the user.

Alternatively, if you want to increase sensitivity, you can simply multiply `amount` by some number.